# Do All HTML attributes require a @ in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, html-helper

I am working on a project that declares html attributes as @class = "className" or @id = "ID" however for this form control it does not happen:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.IsEBSCreated, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Questions:

1. Why does the HTML attribute `disabled` not have an `@` symbol before it?
2. Is the `@` symbol not always required?
3. Does the HTML attribute `checked` require an `@` symbol?

Thank you

Comment: The `@` is used to escape names that would otherwise be C# language keywords (`class`, `checked`, `bool`, `abstract` etc).

Comment: You should use `m` instead of `Model` inside HtmlHelper methods because `Model` is the same name as `this.Model` inside a View - name collisions should be avoided.

Comment: @MartinCostello I see, in that case `id` does not require an `@` But in the code it always has an `@` so I assume it doesn't break anything if its not necessary but present

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the advice that definitely makes sense! I'll change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `@` prefix on an identifier in C# allows language keywords to be used as identifiers, aka *verbatim identifier*.
- Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim
- Note that you don't need to use `@` with C#'s *contextual keywords* like `from` and `where` - [only C#'s *reserved keywords*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/).

> Why does the HTML attribute `disabled` not have an `@` symbol before it?

Because `disabled` is not a C# language keyword.

> Is the `@` symbol not always required?

Only when you're using a C# language keyword as an identifier.

> Does the HTML attribute `checked` require an `@` symbol?

Yes, because `checked` (and `unchecked`) are C# language keywords.

---

For example:

```cs
public interface @interface
{
    string? @string { get; }
}

public class @class : @interface
{
    private static readonly string? @null = null;
    string? @interface.@string => @null;
}
```

Feel free to use the above code in a team project if you happen to dislike a particular member of your team.